# Subnet flowlogs not allowed to be uploaded? but have followed instructions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

I am attempting to publish one of my AWS VPC Subnets flowlogs to CloudWatch.. however it states some permission issue..

[image]

I've checked and rechecked... it says to setup an IAM Role (Which I have) with permissions as follows

Here's the trust policy on the IAM Role

[image]

As well as its permissions setup

[image]

Citations :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/working-with-flow-logs.html

Comment: Have you already validated that your FlowLog is using the correct Role? The IAM Role you're using is set up fine.

Comment: I checked it out and still stuck.. if you want I can append the IAM Role permissions or let me know how best I can show my work so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the answer was... while I had set the permissions for the IAM Role properly within my AWS Organization... the org itself did NOT have ANY permissions enabled to push flow logs.. so I had to go to my root account, edit the organizations permissions... and wipe out and redeploy the flow log..  I can now confirm everything is working fine.

TLDR: If you're using AWS Orgs.. don't forget your global permissions!